# How to make a particular row to take all column space so that data will take overall column space with no border

Tags: html, css

I have difficulty in using all column space of a row with no border.I want to use the whole row space so that data can be displayed in a line.

[image]

As you can see above the grand total is not using whole row it is specific to the column.I have want it to display the way it is in below snapshot.

[image]

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `colspan` attribute for first td of the row you want full width

in your case use `colspan=8` for **grand total4 records** td

Answer (score 0):

Use the `colspan` property of HTML tables. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_colspan).

Answer (score 0):

This what you have to do:

```html
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr style="background:grey;">
<th>Date 1</th>
<th>Fund</th>
<th>Company</th>
<th>Subject</th>
<th>Comments</th>
<th>Date 2</th>
<th>Review</th>
<th>People</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>02/18/2016</td>
<td>test4</td>
<td>test-c5</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>testing</td>
<td>02/08/2016</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>02/18/2016</td>
<td>test4</td>
<td>test-c5</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>testing</td>
<td>02/08/2016</td>
<td>data</td>
<td>data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>02/18/2016</td>
<td>test4</td>
<td>test-c5</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>testing</td>
<td>02/08/2016</td>
<td>data</td>
<td>data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background:grey;">Grand<br/> Totol4<br/> records<br/></td>
<td colspan="7"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]